# com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentConflictException: Session could not be activated due to a conflict with other work in progress

Tags: java, gradle, weblogic

I keep getting this error when I am trying to update an ejb jar on OSB for a transport type Business Service.

```
com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentConflictException: Session could not be activated due to a conflict with other work in progress. Please retry the activation.
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator.commitViaEditService(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:603)
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator.__serverCommit(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:535)
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator.access$200(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:90)
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator$1.run(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:382)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator.serverCommit(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:375)
    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentInitiator.execute(ServerDeploymentInitiator.java:255)
    at com.bea.wli.config.session.impl.SessionManager.commitSessionUnlocked(SessionManager.java:314)
    at com.bea.wli.config.session.impl.SessionManager.commitSession(SessionManager.java:233)
    at com.bea.wli.config.session.impl.SessionManager.commitSession(SessionManager.java:190)
    at com.bea.wli.config.session.impl.SessionManager.commitSession(SessionManager.java:199)
    at com.bea.wli.config.mbeans.Session.commitSession(Session.java:94)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagement.activateSession(SessionManagement.java:30)
    at com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.DelegatedSessionManagementMBeanImpl.activateSession(DelegatedSessionManagementMBeanImpl.java:32)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.invoke(WLSModelMBean.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.internal.FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(FederatedMBeanServerInterceptor.java:351)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:263)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.invoke(SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.java:65)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:444)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.invoke(WLSMBeanServer.java:323)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11$1.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:663)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.invoke(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:654)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I have tried retrying the activation as the stacktrace mentions:

> Session could not be activated due to a conflict with other work in progress. Please retry the activation.

Same error occurs.

What does it mean, and what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was a running change on the bus server. Ended the change from the BUS console's change center, and it worked.

The change center is in the upper left corner of the bus console:

[image: Change center capture]